# Firebase Database Rules: Predefine own variables

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

just wanna ask if this is possible as it would the readability and maintainability of my rules.

```
path fireId = root.child('chat').child('$chatSpecific').child('FireId')

"chatInfo": {
      "$uid":{
          ".read": "fireId.val()===auth.uid"
```

Thanks

Comment: You might want to have a look at Bolt: https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/docs/guide.md

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible,

```
"chatInfo": {
      "$uid":{
          ".read": "data.child('FireId').val()===auth.uid"
       }
    }
```

Comment: data.child('FireId') is enough?? What if 'FireId' is used in a different path as well? Wont this slow down the security checks, I mean its not specified anywhere where FireId is?

Comment: if you use under different childid, i think it will better to index the fireid

Comment: will it work? i mean 'FireId' is not a child of chatInfo but a completely different branch (root.chat) .